# JavaFX ListView item selection

Tags: listview, javafx, mouseevent

My ListView is a set of folders and files and when I click on a folder I replace the entire items with the content of the clicked folder.

I would like to see a background color when I click down on a folder, and enter **the folder only when I release the mouse** BUT right now the item gets selected as soon as I click down.

How can I change the behavior of the selection model to select an item on mouse up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code, I can only guess...

You'll want to use onMouseClick; I'm guessing you are using onMousePressed.